# JPA: How can I return a generic/type class from EntityManager?

Tags: generics, jpa, entity, named-query

How can I make Eclipse understand that I expect a type result from em.createQuery(...)?

```
public class ReservationDaoImpl<T extends SessionInfoEntity<T>> extends JpaDaoImpl<ReservationEntity<T>> 
    implements ReservationDao<T> {
public ReservationEntity<T> findById(final Long reservationId) {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        final TypedQuery<ReservationEntity<T>> resQuery =
                em.createNamedQuery("ReservationEntity.findById", ReservationEntity.class) 
                .setParameter("reservationId", reservationId)
                .setMaxResults(1);
            ReservationEntity<T> resE = null;
            try {
                resE = resQuery.getSingleResult();
            } catch( NoResultException nrEx) {
                //...
            }

            em.close();

            return resE;
    }
}
```

Eclipse complains:
***Type mismatch: cannot convert from TypedQuery<ReservationEntity> to TypedQuery<ReservationEntity<T>>*** when invoking

```
final TypedQuery<ReservationEntity<T>> resQuery = 
    em.createNamedQuery("ReservationEntity.findById", ReservationEntity.class) 
                .setParameter("reservationId", reservationId)
                .setMaxResults(1);
```